# Hive: error calculating SUM then MAX of grouped items

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I would like to run a query that calculates maximum money spent for each month of each credit card. For each credit card, I will need to calculate the sum of money spent each month. I have a table containing transactions of credit cards `credit_transact`:

```
processdate timestamp   ""
cardno_hash string  ""
amount  int ""
year    int ""
month   int ""
```

Made-up sample data:

```
card    year    month    amount
a123    2016    12       23160
a123    2016    10       287
c123    2016    11       5503
c123    2016    11       4206
```

I would like:

```
card    year    month    amount
a123    2016    12       23160
c123    2016    11       9709
```

One important thing is year and month are partition columns.

I have tried a subquery like below:

```
USE credit_card_db;
SELECT sum_amount_transact.cardno_hash, sum_amount_transact.year, sum_amount_transact.month, MAX(sum_amount_transact.sum_amount)
FROM
(
  SELECT cardno_hash, year, month, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount FROM credit_transact
  GROUP BY cardno_hash, year, month
) AS sum_amount_transact
GROUP BY sum_amount_transact.cardno_hash, sum_amount_transact.year;
```

However, the following error is shown:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 0:-1 Invalid column reference 'month'
```

The following subquery worked fine and returned results as expected:

```
SELECT cardno_hash, year, month, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount FROM credit_transact
  GROUP BY cardno_hash, year, month
```

The result is:

```
card    year    month    amount
a123    2016    12       23160
a123    2016    10       287
c123    2016    11       9709
```

Would very much appreciate if anyone can help with this problem.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  You can make up reasonable data if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I can't sample the data, because the data is confidential.

Comment: I believe month is a reserved keyword with Hive.  Have you tried naming the column something else?

Comment: I have run the subquery which worked well, so I think it is unlikely to be the case.  I have also checked the reserved keywords list, but it is in the non-reserved column.

Comment: Why aren't you expecting a row for month 10 in your desired result?  Was that intentional?

Comment: Yes, it is intentional, because month 12 has the highest sum amount for card a123. You can see in the subquery result and compare with the result I would like  (MAX applied).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite tell what you really want, but I'm pretty sure you want `row_number()`.  I think you want the maximum month per year:

```
SELECT ct.*
FROM (SELECT cardno_hash, year, month, SUM(amount) AS sum_amount,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cardno_hash, year ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM credit_transact
      GROUP BY cardno_hash, year, month
     ) ct
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I have editted the question to include sample data, hope it helps

Comment: @LongLe . . . This query should be doing what you want.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cardno_hash, year ORDER BY SUM(amount) DESC) as seqnum` I do not understand this very much

Comment: @LongLe . . . You can find lots of resources on the web . . . http://dwgeek.com/hadoop-hive-analytic-functions-examples.html/.